# Uncaught TypeError: this.getKeyCode is not a function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

In my backbone view i have a function that calls another function defined in the same view like this:

```
View.FormCustomer = CommonViews.FormCustomer.extend({
        title : "Ajouter une fiche client",
        events : {
            "keypress  .customerForm" : "getKeyCodeD"
        },
        getKeyCode : function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == "13") {
                this.save(e);
            }
        },
        getKeyCodeD : function(e) {
            $(document).on('keypress.namespace', function(e) {
                this.getKeyCode(e);
            });
    },
```

When i invoke the getKeyCodeD  function by pressing a key i got an error that says `Uncaught TypeError: this.getKeyCode is not a function`

I think the `$(document).on` is the problem because when i invoke the getKeyCode function directly there is no problem in calling `this.save(e);`

How can i solve this without making `$(document).on` in the initialize ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with scope change. `this` keyword points to `#document` during execution, so you should re-bind the scope you want - the backbone class:

```
$(document).on('keypress.namespace', function(e) {
    this.getKeyCode(e);
}).bind( this );
```

Here is [workaround](http://jsfiddle.net/C9wew/7840).

Comment: With your proposition i got another error
Uncaught TypeError: handlers.push is not a function

Comment: Can I try the code somewhere, so I would be able to help you?

Comment: Not sure this is exactly what you need, but take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/C9wew/7837/

Comment: Actualyy what i need is when i press enter i execute the dosearch this is why i verify if the keycode is 13 before